# how to set the environment value manually to integer zero in C

Tags: c, linux

> I have to manually set value of  ENVIRONMENT initially to integer 0.
>    Through the below function I will try to retrieve it and set it again to the deisred value.

```
int abcd()
{
    int temp1=0,temp2;
    temp1++;
    char *env=NULL;
    env=getenv("ENVIRONMENT");
    sscanf(env,"%d",&temp2);
    temp2=temp2+temp1;
    printf("%d",temp2);
    sprintf(temp2,"%d",env);
    setenv("ENVIRONMENT",env,0);
}
```

> all the integer variabes are 32 bit unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what `gcc` thinks

```
nil.c:12:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
nil.c:12:1: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’


   sprintf(temp2,"%d",env);
           ¯¯¯¯¯      ¯¯¯
```

Looks like it's saying your arguments are the wrong type. What's `sprintf`'s manual page say?

```
  int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Hmm. I'll bet you thought you'd like to do this…

```
  sprintf (env, "%d", temp2);
```

But wait … how big is the buffer that `env` points to? Will it fit every possible value that `temp2` might hold, plus the mandatory `\0` terminator?

`getenv` manual says:

```
   RETURN VALUE

   The  getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL
   if there is no match.
```

Uh'oh. “In the environment!” We probably shouldn't write to that buffer!

```
   BUGS

   Because sprintf() and vsprintf() assume an arbitrarily long string, callers  must
   be  careful not to overflow the actual space; this is often impossible to assure.
   Note that the length of the strings produced is locale-dependent and difficult to
   predict.    Use   snprintf()   and   vsnprintf()   instead  (or  asprintf(3)  and
   vasprintf(3)).
```

Oh, that `asprintf` sounds like a good idea…

```
   int asprintf(char **strp, const char *fmt, ...);

   DESCRIPTION

   The   functions   asprintf()  and  vasprintf()  are  analogs  of  sprintf(3)  and
   vsprintf(3), except that they allocate a string large enough to hold  the  output
   including  the  terminating  null  byte, and return a pointer to it via the first
   argument.  This pointer should be passed to  free(3)  to  release  the  allocated
   storage when it is no longer needed.

   RETURN VALUE

   When  successful,  these  functions return the number of bytes printed, just like
   sprintf(3).  If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some  other  error  occurs,
   these functions will return -1, and the contents of strp is undefined.
```

EDITED:
In response to comment, I had not noticed this other bug:

```
   DESCRIPTION
   The  setenv()  function  adds the variable name to the environment with the value
   value, if name does not already exist.  If name does exist  in  the  environment,
   then its value is changed to value if overwrite is nonzero; if overwrite is zero,
   then the value of name is not changed.  This function makes copies of the strings
   pointed to by name and value (by contrast with putenv(3)).


  setenv ("ENVIRONMENT", "0", 0);
                              ¯
```

You also probably want to enable overwriting the value.

I was going to encourage you to refactor it yourself, but putting together what the compiler and manual say, we get:

```
int abcd()
{
    /* Set up automatic variables with default values */
    const int temp1 = 1;
    int env_value = 0;
    char *old_env = NULL;
    char *new_env = NULL;

    /* Let's see if this is set in the environment */
    old_env = getenv ("ENVIRONMENT");
    /* Was it set? And, if so, can we get a decimal integer from it? */
    if (NULL != old_env 
        && 1 == sscanf (old_env, "%d", &env_value)) {
            /* OK, both library functions succeeded, so let's increment… */
            env_value += temp1;
    }
    /* Log the output */    
    printf ("new env value = %d\n", env_value);
    /* Let's allocate a new buffer and write the string version of
     * this number to it */
    asprintf (&new_env, "%d", env_value);
    /* Note … forgot to check success of asprintf!
     * Correcting this bug left as an excercise to the reader. */

    /* Copy the new value into the environment, overwriting if necessary */
    setenv ("ENVIRONMENT", new_env, !0);
    /* Clean up that buffer! */
    free (new_env);
}
```

Comment: what my intention is that 
first convert the env to integer temp2 qnd then increment it
after incrementing i want that temp2 to get converted in char value so as to set withat value in setenv.

But initially i want that ENVIORONMENT should be integer zero

Comment: :thanku very much for this correction.

But can u tell how to initially set value to zero for ENVIRONMENT.

currently i am setting by using command setenv ENVIRONMENT 0

Comment: hey that temp2 whisch u r using in asprintf is env_value only?

Comment: oops. fixed, yes. Do you mean, how to set the enironment in your shell? probably `setenv ENVIRONMENT 0` as you say; else `export ENVIRONMENT=0`

Comment: i tried to do this but when i am checking the condition if(env!=NULL) it is returning false

Comment: if `(env != NULL) == FALSE` then `(env == NULL)`, which the manual says: “RETURN VALUE: The  getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL if there is no match.”

Comment: so what should i do
i iniilly want to set ENVIRONMENT to integer 0